# Start Laravel Schedular on Laradock - Cron Jobs

Tags: laravel-5, cron, laradock

I have a laravel project hosted locally on Docker CE Windows 10 Pro. I cannot find any documentation on how to start the schedular in the workspace container.

Laradock docs only tell you where to add additional cron jobs but nothing over how to setup the schedular the first time. I saw the crontab inside the workspace container, but it is not working. Is there anything i must do to make it start?

Comment: http://laradock.io/documentation/#adding-cron-jobs I think cron jobs started automatically for me. However, I'm not sure how to get Supervisor working: https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/14